# jenkins Access Denied- asdf@gmail.com is missing the Read permission

Tags: security, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

i am using Jenkins war 1.520 in Ubuntu 12.04 i had configured jenkins with openid plugin and authenticated with Google apps. I made some changes in role based security and matrix based security why prompts me

`Access Denied- asdf@gmail.com is missing the Read permission`

please let me know, what needs to be done in order to get the access to jenkins

Comment: You will have to reconfigure your permissions. Do you still have a user with login access or not ?

Comment: i can do simple login, that's all

Comment: As said in my answer, if you have disabled security and are able to log, reenable it, ad show us what you have in your matrix and role based security.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins Github Authentication error: user is missing the Overall/Read permission](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22717773/jenkins-github-authentication-error-user-is-missing-the-overall-read-permission)

Answer (score 5):

You will have to reconfigure your permissions. Do you still have a user with login access or not ? If not you might have to reset it by temporarily disabling the security. This can be achieved by modifying the $JENKINS_HOME/config.xml ($HOME/.jenkins/config.xml by default when running the jenkins.war on your system) and setting <useSecurity> from true to false. Be sure to backup your config!

Once you are there reenable the security, and show us what you have in matrix and role based security.

Comment: i don't find the config.xml file and i am using war file. Please do let me know the ways. my jenkins is idle for two days!

Comment: When jenkins starts, it 'explodes' the war file into a location and starts writing configuration file. You will probably find it under $HOME/.jenkins/config.xml. Backup that directory (or just that file if you are cautious enough), edit the config file as recommended above, restart jenkins.

Comment: in my case, file location is /var/lib/jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue with Jenkins, turns out my user name was Gideon but error I was getting was 'gideon is missing the overall administer/register permission'. Edited config.xml by changing Gideon to gideon in the /hudson/authorizationStrategy/permission tags and everything is working fine now.

Comment: I had some trouble with authentication, too, and this is what helped me. The user was spelled Viciouss but it turned out that viciouss was actually the name I had to add for permissions to work. This took quite some time to realize.

Answer (score 0):

My permissions file was here:

`/var/lib/jenkins/config.xml`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in [Disable security](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Disable+security) page, you need to edit `config.xml` in your `$JENKINS_HOME` (e.g. `/var/lib/jenkins`) and remove lines with `useSecurity`, `authorizationStrategy` and `securityRealm`, then restart Jenkins.

See: [Jenkins Github Authentication error: user is missing the Overall/Read permission](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22717773/55075)