# 'User is missing the Overall/Read permission' error with Jenkins GitHub OAuth Plugin

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm using the [github oauth plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Github+OAuth+Plugin) for our logins but for all of our users in the Organisation I get an error:

```
Access Denied

<user> is missing the Overall/Read permission
```

I have tried everything I can possibly think of to try to make this work and I'm probably going to fallback to making everyone an admin user, which i would prefer not to do.

Any advise would be appreciated.

Answer (score 74):

This is how I resolved the authentication problem:

1. Edit `config.xml` file, e.g.

   ```
   sudo vi /var/lib/jenkins/config.xml
   ```

   1. Change `useSecurity` element's value to `false`, e.g.

      ```
      <useSecurity>false</useSecurity>
      ```
   2. Remove `authorizationStrategy` block
2. Restart Jenkins: `/etc/init.d/jenkins restart`.
3. Access Jenkins through URL as usual and reconfigure security again.

Comment: Just like on the dancefloor, back that thang up: cp -R /var/lib/jenkins /var/lib/BACKUP-jenkins

Comment: Note that the question is about how to make security work, not how to restart Jenkins without security to be able to access it.

Comment: True but, thanks so much I thought I had lost my jenkins installation after locking the administrator out by accident

Comment: If we do this all current users will lose their user name and password right and have to create a new password all user? what if I just have reset permission of one user only?

Comment: We just experienced similar issue. 
It happened after adding a new user to role. 
To resolve it I changed useSecurity to false, restarted the Jenkins, then stopped Jenkins again and reverted the parameter to be true... somehow it solved the issue. 
Would happy to know if someone knows RC for this problem and how to prevent in the future.

Comment: I googled a bit more and found why is happened on our machine.
Similar case as here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51790352/1085076

Answer (score 25):

I had the same problem with "... is missing the Overall/Read permission" on Jenkins (1.651.2) with activated Credentials Plugin.

But it was my own failure: I only configured the user on project side (by credential plugin) but missed to configure the global security.

So I fixed it by selecting:

> Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure Global Security

And did setup missing global settings (or project matrix based one)

Comment: Thank you. Your solution was awesome when i added new user. I faced the same error and resolved.

Comment: Yes, this is the right answer without compromising the Security. Thanks

Answer (score 18):

Have you followed this step, from the plugin page?

`Control user authorization (i.e. who is allowed to see the jobs and build them) using the Github Commiter Authorization Strategy`

Also, make sure you actually allow authenticated users to access Jenkins

- Under Jenkins global configuration, under Authorization, add user/group called `authenticated`
- Give that group Overall Read permission
- The group should show up with a "group" icon (two users), as opposed to single user icon.

Comment: Yes i added our organisation, Blooie, to the list but the members of the organisation can't login. They all get the above error

Comment: Did you setup `authenticated` group to have permissions at all? I've updated the answer

Comment: Ok so now i'm really really confused... you ask if i followed the step from the plugin page and this is all that step says: https://cloudup.com/cfbsnzHGBxA . I'm using the github authorization strategy and my users are public members of our organisation.

Now you're talking about "Global Configuration", I assume that you mean "Global Security Configuration" https://cloudup.com/cfFzfQ8bYol 

I've gone to the Authorization section in the Global Security Configuration and i don't see anything related to groups: https://cloudup.com/cdPRoZ0xqxT 

Am i missing something?

Comment: I assume that the comments about 'authenticated' group are assuming that you are using "Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy" -- which it sounds like you are not:  https://i.imgsafe.org/218e656913.png

Answer (score 6):

reset from `<useSecurity>true</useSecurity>` to `<useSecurity>false</useSecurity>` in config.xml and set the permission again.

Comment: I think this is simpler than removing entire blocks of XML

Answer (score 5):

What I did when I got this error is to edit config.xml as mentionned by other users and correctly re-add my username in LOWERCASE in "configureSecurity" Jenkins' page. I was using "KrustyHack" when adding permissions but it didn't work. I had to add "krustyhack" instead, and it worked.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I had the problem in the question and fixed it in the similar way as this answer mentions. However, I did that editing the config directly: `sed -i '' -e 's/:Admin/:admin/g' Home/config.xml`. a little bit more information is here: http://www.egeek.me/2015/03/07/jenkins-admin-is-missing-the-overall-read-permission/

Answer (score 5):

Edit file /var/lib/jenkins/config.xml and add the following lines :

```
  <authorizationStrategy class="hudson.security.ProjectMatrixAuthorizationStrategy">
    <permission>hudson.model.Hudson.Read:john.smith</permission>
  </authorizationStrategy>
```

Restart Jenkins

Comment: Nice and succinct. Saves faffing about with turning security off and on again, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem here, but it affected only some users, not all of them. Anyway, you should check public organization membership : documentation of the plugin states that "You have to be a public member of the organization for the authorization to work correctly." (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Github+OAuth+Plugin).

Follow instructions from GitHub (https://help.github.com/articles/publicizing-or-hiding-organization-membership/) in order to make organization membership public, and this might fix your issue.

Answer (score 3):

Also check the case user names in the `authorizationStrategy` element.  I made my new user's name lower case and restarted the service and it the error went away.

Comment: My user was getting an error of FRED@mycompany.com is missing the Overall/Read permission. I had that user in my jenkins matrix as fred@mycompany.com. As soon as I added FRED@mycompany.com to the Jenkins matrix, that user could login ok.

Answer (score 3):

Fix it by these 2 shell commands on the server (sudo permission is required):

```
sudo ex +g/useSecurity/d +g/authorizationStrategy/d -scwq /var/lib/jenkins/config.xml
sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins restart
```

This will remove `useSecurity` and `authorizationStrategy` lines from your config file.

See also: [Disable security](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Disable+security) at Jenkins website

Answer (score 2):

We hit this same error when a github organization administrator changed the organization's settings for "Third-party access" to "restrict third-party application access". Reverting to the previous settings within the github organization resolved the problem.

See [github oauth-app-access-restrictions](https://help.github.com/articles/about-oauth-app-access-restrictions/) for details on how to configure that properly.

Answer (score 2):

The assignment of roles to users is stored in `config.xml` file. Add the ID of the user directly to the role and then restart Jenkins.

In my case, I have a role named `editor` and a bunch of users assigned to the role.

```
 <role name="editor" pattern=".*">
     <permissions>
         <...>
         <permission>hudson.model.Item.Create</permission>
         <permission>hudson.model.Item.Workspace</permission>
         <permission>...</permission>
     </permissions>
     <assignedSIDs>
         <sid>bob</sid>
         <sid>alice</sid>
         <sid>**newuser**</sid>   
     </assignedSIDs>
  </role>
```

Answer (score 1):

The matrix security is not terribly clear. I am a member of a specific group in our org that has admin privileges however I am also an authenticated user. I would think that the one group super-cedes the other however I have to have both in order to actually log into the system and be admin. It's screwed up IMO.

Answer (score 1):

go to `your-jenkins-host:port/role-strategy/assign-roles` and configure roles for the user

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Go to $JENKINS_HOME (linux, jenkins in windows), and find config.xml file.
- Open this file in the editor. (take backup of .jenkins home)
- Look for the `<useSecurity>true</useSecurity>` element in this file.
- Replace "true" with "false"
- Remove the elements `authorizationStrategy` and `securityRealm`
- Start Jenkins

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before,
your OAuth application need your organization owner's approve,
then the OAuth Plugin can access the private data in it

Answer (score 0):

I am using Crowd 2 plugin and I have the same problem. 
I fixed it by downgrading OWASP Markup Formatter Plugin from varsion 1.2 to version 1.1 and then changing Markup Formatter in Configure Global Security value to Raw HTML, before it was Plain text.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem and adding the plugin Role Strategy Plugin fixed the problem.

All I had to do was install the plugin, create two groups - admin / developer and then add users to the groups.

A much much better solution than recreating the whole permissions matrix :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem I was not able access  Jenkin account and the system was locked.
 I had only an error message. "Access Denied "

When I  tried to reinstall Jenkins then it prompted to Repair option. 
By clicking Repair option it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found it in
`C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins`

Jenkins Version: **2.319.2**

[image: Image1]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing all security (the top answer), Add admin access as root, to the user you want to give admin to. We had the same issue where all admins were no longer with the company.     This is how I resolved the authentication problem: I logged into:

```
 jenkins@<jenkins server>:/var/lib/jenkins/
```

Edit config.xml file, and add a config for

```
<permission>hudson.model.Hudson.Administer:<username></permission>
```

Then restart Jenkins:

```
root@<jenkins server>:/$ /etc/init.d/jenkins restart
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use Jenkins > Configure Global Security bottom page matrix to provide permissions to the user (start w/ read)

Comment: I can't access that, the system is locked and all I can see is this error message.

Answer (score -1):

I edited the /var/lib/jenkins/config.xml file and replaced the

```
<authorizationStrategy>...</authorizationStrategy>
```

with

```
<authorizationStrategy class="hudson.security.FullControlOnceLoggedInAuthorizationStrategy">
    <denyAnonymousReadAccess>true</denyAnonymousReadAccess>
</authorizationStrategy>
```

It is the default settings after installation. Then restart the jenkins service.