# Access Denied : UserXXX is missing the Overall/Read permission

Tags: ios, jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins-build-flow

I am working with jenkins, unfortunately i was added one user as admin I forgot that password for that user, So when i try to login with other users its showing like below image. I was trying to set false to userSecurity in config.xml and restart the jenkins but it was not fixed. please suggest me how to overcome this issue

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins Github Authentication error: user is missing the Overall/Read permission](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22717773/jenkins-github-authentication-error-user-is-missing-the-overall-read-permission)

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit `config.xml` file in `/var/lib/jenkins` and remove the lines with `useSecurity` and `authorizationStrategy`, then restart Jenkins.

Related:

- [Jenkins Github Authentication error: user is missing the Overall/Read permission](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22717773/55075)
- [Disable security at Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Disable+security)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about your Jenkins home folder?

If you are working with Linux, you can have a look to the Jenkins process with:

```
ps aux | grep jenkins
```

Next, you can check where is your home folder:

```
etc/alternatives/java -Dcom.sun...... -DJENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins
```

Comment: I am working with Mac , my jenkins home is at  /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home

Answer (score 0):

Try removing elements authorizationStrategy and securityRealm? [Sample Reference Link](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Disable+security)

Comment: yes even I tested by removing authorizationStrategy and securityRealm, But no use.

Comment: you said that jenkins shows UserXXX is missing the Overall/Read permission. After deleting authorizationStrategy you shoud have no users and be unable to login on any account. Maybe somethings left in your config.xml file. And restart computer, not only jenkins.