# Login error at Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

For the continuous integration I am using Jenkins. I have installed a fresh Jenkins following *[Installing Jenkins on Ubuntu](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Ubuntu)*.

As:

```
wget -q -O - https://jenkins-ci.org/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key | sudo apt-key add -

sudo sh -c 'echo deb http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian binary/ > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install jenkins
```

Restart the Jenkins server as `$ sudo service jenkins restart`.

And browse at `localhost:8080`.

I have signed up for administrator, and when I am going to log in the first time there is a error like this:

**`admin is missing the Overall/Read permission.`**

How do I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins Github Authentication error: user is missing the Overall/Read permission](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22717773/jenkins-github-authentication-error-user-is-missing-the-overall-read-permission)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22717773/jenkins-github-authentication-error-user-is-missing-the-overall-read-permission . this not what that gives the answer for my problem

Comment: i have a fresh installation of jenkins, and for the first time login it does cause the error.

Comment: May be you installed jenkins on a server with garbadge from previous Jenkins installations, try:

-Stop Jenkins, find config.xml file in $JENKINS_HOME, Look for the <useSecurity>true</useSecurity> element in this file, Replace true with false, Start Jenkins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the $JENKINS_HOME directory, /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/ in my case, there is the users/directory which stores some user info, and it had an admin directory. So far so good. The user seemed to be alive.

I went to $JENKINS_HOME/config.xml and it had permission tags like this:
1 2 3

`<permission>hudson.model.Computer.Build:Admin</permission><permission>hudson.model.Computer.Configure:Admin</permission> <permission>hudson.model.Computer.Connect:Admin</permission>`

Do you see any inconsistency?

Yes, the Admin user here starts with a capital letter for some reason. Could that be a problem? I changed all Admin to admin in the file and restarted Jenkins.

Comment: To be clear, did you have a problem, changed to lowercase, and the problem went away?