# Jenkins CLI : ERROR: anonymous is missing the Overall/Read permission

Tags: jenkins, command-line-interface, ssh-keys, jenkins-cli

I'm stuck with this problem and I have no idea to solve it.

I have written a Shell script which will invoke my job using Jenkins CLI by passing my private key.Jenkins version is 2.121.1

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa build RTT/RTT-CI-Tools/RTT-CI-Tools-Distribute -s -p SLAVE_REGEX=testserver
```

Getting Error message as :

```
ERROR: anonymous is missing the Overall/Read permission
```

The same script works in another Jenkins (2.7.4). How to fix this issue.

Comment: it's a permission issue you need give access to anonymous

Comment: The script works in another jenkins where we didnt provide any access to anonymous.

Comment: you must give access if you want to run something especially in linux ....you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22717773/jenkins-github-authentication-error-user-is-missing-the-overall-read-permission

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please check for below points

`1) USER exist on jenkins server as same on linux machine.`

`2) SSH Public key shared on Jenkins server is correct.(manage jenkins --> manage user --> click on ${USER} --> click on configure --> then check ssh public key is correct).`

`3) CMD i used(working) --> java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -ssh -user ${USER} -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -s http://localhost:8080/jenkins/ build ${JOB_NAME}`

please check if you are executing cmd from same user.

`4) SSH port should be enable on Jenkins (go to manage Jenkins--> configure Global security --> SSH Server... set SSHD Port Fixed eg 38844)`

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. I also had to open access to Jenkins port 38844 from bastion host, because my Jenkins was in a private subnet.

Answer (score 10):

You can also use auth param but you should to type your password in console

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ -auth myLoggin:myPassword list-jobs
```

Comment: You can, but exposing passwords as open text isn't a good practice.

Answer (score 4):

This issue cropped up for me, too, recently (using the cli to automate installing jenkins). I was able to work around it by setting the `denyAnonymousReadAccess` flag to `false` in jenkins' `config.xml` file, and restarting jenkins:

```
  <authorizationStrategy class="hudson.security.FullControlOnceLoggedInAuthorizationStrategy">  
    <denyAnonymousReadAccess>false</denyAnonymousReadAccess>  
  </authorizationStrategy>
```